# Customizing bootstrap-vue components

Tags: bootstrap-vue

Starting a large application with a handful of developers.  Using webpack and bootstrap-vue. How would I default the style for <b-card> (and other components).  In other words can I default:

```
<b-card>
```

to be the equivalent to:

```
<b-card style="max-width: 40rem;" header-bg-variant="primary" header-text-variant="white">
```

to make sure we keep our look consistent throughout the whole application.

Comment: Or is the answer to make my own component, my-card, that does that defaulting for them?

Comment: You can control Bootstrap's CSS via SCSS variables (need to add sass loader in your build steps). and you can also create a custom CSS file to load after bootstrap/bootstrap-vue css files that overrides class styles... `.card { max-width: 40rem }`

Comment: Consider making a custom component that wraps `b-card`, which passes the default slot to `b-card` and applies the preferred props/styles to `b-card`

Answer (score 3):

You can either use SCSS/CSS overrides to control the b-card layout, or extend/wrap the component to default the props you want:

```js
import { BCard } from 'bootstrap-vue'

export default {
  name 'MyCard',
   // Create as a functional component wrapper
  functional: true,
  // define our props (borrow from BCard)
  props: {
    ...BCard.props,
  },
  render(h, { props, data, children }) {
    return h(
      BCard,
      {
        props: {
          // Pass all props to BCard
          ...props,
          // Override the following prop defaults (if not provided)
          headerBgVariant: props.headerBgVariant || 'primary',
          headerTextVariant: props.headerBgVariant || 'white'
        },
        // Pass any additional (optional) attributes down
        attrs: data.attrs,
        // Set the style
        style: {
          // merge in any styles manually applied
          ...data.style,
          // Set the max-width if not explicitly set
          maxWidth: data.style.maxWidth || '40rem'
        }
      }
    )
  }
}
```

For more info on functional components and render functions, see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components

For handling more complex data merges with functional components, check out https://github.com/alexsasharegan/vue-functional-data-merge